# Is this a valid proof that $\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x^2-9}{5-\sin(7x)}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Prove $$\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x^2-9}{5-\sin(7x)}=0$$

Proof:

Given $\epsilon >0$, choose $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{7})$.

Then $|x-3|<1$ means $|x|-|3|\leq|x-3|<1$ so $|x|<4$.

So $|\frac{x^2-9}{5-\sin(7x)}|<|x^2-9|=|(x-3)(x+3)|<7\frac{\epsilon}{7}=\epsilon$.

Comment: Easier: The denominator goes to a non-zero number (it is certainly $\ge 4$), while the numerator goes to zero. So the entire fraction goes to zero.

Comment: Looks fine, although just to be sure i would take $\epsilon/2$ in place of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Even for the sake of an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ type proof, this looks rather weird. In the first sentence, no matter how logically correct it is, the way you choose $\delta$ would be very mysterious until one reads the later part of your proof. 
I would rather do it as the following.

- Show that $c<|5-\sin(7x)|<C$ for some constants $c,C>0$.
- Show that $\lim_{x\to 3}x^2-9=0$. (Whatever method you like, maybe with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ language.)
- Combine the results above to give an argument for the desired limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is fine. If you want to be formal, you have to argue that $5-\sin 7x>1$ (not that it's hard...)